# Reducing the number of terms in Waring-Goldbach problem by allowing exponents to vary

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbach-type-problems

Assuming the Waring-Goldbach problem (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%E2%80%93Goldbach_problem) has a positive solution, can we reduce the number of terms $t$ to some value $t'$ by allowing the $t'$ exponents to take $1<u<t$ different values?

Indeed it seems to me that requiring the exponents to be all the same is too strong a constraint preventing $t$ to be small. Can we for example hope to get that every large enough integer $N$ fulfilling some congruence condition modulo $t'$ is the sum of $t':=t+1-u$ terms of the form $p_{i}^{k_{i}}$ with $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^{t'}k_{i}=tk}$?

Comment: You probably want to constrain the $k_i$ to avoid trivial reductions to known 
(albeit very nontrivial) results, for starters, any choice with $k_1=k_2=k_3=1$
follows from ternary Goldbach.

Comment: No, not necessarily.

Comment: Actually, my goal is to get closer to (binary) Goldbach.

Comment: https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~ford/wwwpapers/trnsup1.pdf    and https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~ford/wwwpapers/trnsup2.pdf  .